# npm unable to find correct version of package within Docker

Tags: node.js, docker, npm

I am attempting to perform npm install within a docker image. As part of the package.json, I need version 1.8.8 of react-pattern-library. Within the docker image, only version 0.0.1 appears to be available.

If I locally run

```
npm view react-pattern-library versions
```

I can see version 1.8.8

However the same command within my docker file only show version 0.0.1

Can anyone tell me what configuration setting I need to be able to find the correct version when attempting my docker build?

```
docker build -t jhutc/molly-ui
```

Contents of Dockerfile

```
FROM node:10

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
# where available (npm@5+)
#COPY package*.json ./
COPY package.json ./

RUN npm set strict-ssl false

ENV HTTP_PROXY="http://proxy.company.com:8080"
ENV HTTPS_PROXY="https://proxy.company.com:8080"
RUN echo $HTTP_PROXY
RUN echo $HTTPS_PROXY

RUN npm view react-pattern-library versions

#RUN npm install
```

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting the package-lock.json and running npm install again.